# shell.cd "No directory name could be guessed"

Tags: node.js, shell, github, devops

I want to use a nodejs script to clone and do some other ops at a given repo. However, whenever I do `shell.cd(path)` as seen below it crashes with the

> "No directory name could be guessed"

Here's the script

```
    const nodeCron = require("node-cron");
const shell = require('shelljs');
const path = './';
require('dotenv').config();
const start = Date.now();

async function GitOps(){
    console.log("Running scheduled job", start);
    shell.cd(path);
    shell.exec('git clone -b dev https://',process.env.USERNAME,':',process.env.PASSWORD,'@github.com:Jamesmosley/xyz-git-ops.git');
    return console.log("Job finished");
}

const job = nodeCron.schedule("* * * * *", GitOps);
```

I mean to clone right into my working directory. I tried some stuff like adding 'pwd' at the const path and adding the root folder at the end of the clone command, to no avail:

```
shell.exec('git clone -b dev https://',process.env.USERNAME,':',process.env.PASSWORD,'@github.com:Jamesmosley/xyz-git-ops.git' ./);
```

Answer (score 0):

After all, the only thing missing was literaly pasting my absolute path into the path variable:

```
const path = '/Users/Jamesmosley/Documents/Git Ops Cron/repos';
```

then doing `shell.cd(path)`